# how to filter multi array list in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have tried to implement a search functionality from a list that has multi-array. So I want to search the particular keyword from the array. I have tried but it throws an error.

***Array to search from:***

```js
const listComponent = [{
    id: 0,
    title: "Common",
    subMenu: [{
      image: "",
      secTitle: "",
      subTitle: ""
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Compute",
    subMenu: [{
        image: require("../../assets/images/scaling.png"),
        secTitle: "one comp",
        subTitle: ""
      },
      {
        image: require("../../assets/images/ec2.png"),
        secTitle: "two comp",
        subTitle: ""
      },
      {
        image: require("../../assets/images/lambda.png"),
        secTitle: "three comp",
        subTitle: ""
      },
      {
        image: require("../../assets/images/zone.png"),
        secTitle: "four comp",
        subTitle: ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Second",
    subMenu: [{
      image: "",
      secTitle: "",
      subTitle: ""
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Third",
    subMenu: [{
      image: "",
      secTitle: "",
      subTitle: ""
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "Fourth",
    subMenu: [{
      image: "",
      secTitle: "",
      subTitle: ""
    }]
  }
];
```

***Class Declaration:***

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    components: listComponent,
    filterResult: listComponent
  };

  this.filterComponents = this.filterComponents.bind(this);
}



UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.setState({
    components: nextProps.components
  });
}
```

***Fiter logic:***

```
filterComponents = event => {
  let value = event.target.value;
  let components = this.state.components;

  let filterResult = components.filter(
    component =>
      component.subMenu.findIndex(sub =>
        sub.secTitle.toLowerCase().includes(value)
      ) !== -1
  );

  console.log(filterResult);

  this.setState({ filterResult });
};
```

***JSX:***

```
<ul className="listAll">
  {this.state.filterResult.map((items, key) => (
    <li key={key}>
      <div className="compTitle" onClick={()=> this.openCloseComponent(items.id)} >
        <p>{items.title}</p>
        {this.state.isComOpen === items.id && this.state.isOpen ? (
        <KeyboardArrowDown className="compArrow" /> ) : (
        <KeyboardArrowUp className="compArrow" /> )}
      </div>
      <ul className={ this.state.isComOpen===i tems.id && this.state.isOpen ? "displayBlock secondDrop" : "displayNone" }>
        {items.subMenu.map((submenu, i) => (
          <li key={i}>
            <img src={submenu.image} alt="" />
            <div>
              <p className="secTitle">{submenu.secTitle}</p>
              <p className="subTitle">{submenu.subTitle}</p>
            </div>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
{this.state.filterResult.length === 0 && (
  <p className="noComp">No components found</p>
)}
```

### Problem

I want to search `secTitle` in `subMenu`. The keyword that matches any `secTitle` should be displayed and `other` should be hidden. The **about** code throws an error.

So how do I fix it, any answers will be appreciated!

If I search `one comp` the output should be

```
{
  id: 1,
  title: "Compute",
  subMenu: [
    {
      image: require("../../assets/images/scaling.png"),
      secTitle: "one comp",
      subTitle: ""
    }
  ]
}
```

but now the output is,

```
{
  id: 1,
  title: "Compute",
  subMenu: [
    {
      image: require("../../assets/images/scaling.png"),
      secTitle: "one comp",
      subTitle: ""
    },
    {
      image: require("../../assets/images/ec2.png"),
      secTitle: "two comp",
      subTitle: ""
    },
    {
      image: require("../../assets/images/lambda.png"),
      secTitle: "three comp",
      subTitle: ""
    },
    {
      image: require("../../assets/images/zone.png"),
      secTitle: "four comp",
      subTitle: ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I think your problem is that the [index] is referring to component index instead of subMenu index, therefore you have to iterate each submenu for each component

Comment: @GlenK can you show it in the above code.

Comment: I added a snippet and a simpler version to show what the code should look like in my answer below

Comment: @JithinVarghese i have added an answer below please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing the key for subMenu. Ideally, you should not use an index as a key as the length and the order of subMenu might change. As Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed.

trying changing to this.

```
              ...
              {items.subMenu.map((submenu, i) => (
                  <li
                    key={`${submenu.secTitle}-${i}`}
                  >
                    <img src={submenu.image} alt="" />
                    <div>
                      <p className="secTitle">{submenu.secTitle}</p>
                      <p className="subTitle">{submenu.subTitle}</p>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                ))}
                ...
```

```js
// For case-insensitive search

const result = [];

listComponent.forEach((component, index)=> {
  const comp = {...component};
  if(Array.isArray(comp.subMenu)) {
   comp.subMenu = comp.subMenu.filter((subMenu)=> {
     return subMenu.secTitle.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase());
   });

   if( comp.subMenu.length > 0) {
    result.push(comp);
   }
  }
});
```

```js
// For case-sensitive search

const result = [];

listComponent.forEach((component, index)=> {
  const comp = {...component};
  if(Array.isArray(comp.subMenu)) {
   comp.subMenu = comp.subMenu.filter((subMenu)=> {
     return subMenu.secTitle.includes(value);
   });

   if( comp.subMenu.length > 0) {
    result.push(comp);
   }
  }
});
```

Comment: i'm glad it helped out

Comment: @JithinVarghese please accept and upvote the answer if it worked for you :)

Answer (score 5):

instead of

```
filterResult = components.filter((component, index) => {
  console.log(component.subMenu[index].secTitle);
  return component.subMenu[index].secTitle.toLowerCase().search(value) !== -1;
});
```

The code should look something like this:

```
const listComponent = [
{
    id: 0,
    title: "Common",
    subMenu: [
    {
        image: "",
        secTitle: "abc",
        subTitle: ""
    }
    ]
},
{
    id: 1,
    title: "Common",
    subMenu: [
    {
        image: "",
        secTitle: "def",
        subTitle: ""
    }
    ]
}
]

let value = "abc";

let filterResult = listComponent.filter((component) => {
  return component.subMenu.findIndex((sub) => {
    return sub.secTitle === value;
  }) >= 0;
});

console.log(filterResult);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a combination of `Array.filter` and `Array.findIndex` to get the desired result.
Use `String.includes` to match the substring in secTitle

```
filterResult = filterResult.filter((component) => {
    const hasMatchingSubMenu = component.subMenu.findIndex((sub) => sub.secTitle.includes(value)) !== -1;
    if(hasMatchingSubMenu) {
        component.subMenu = component.subMenu.filter((sub) => sub.secTitle.includes(value));
    }
    return hasMatchingSubMenu;
});
```

Comment: Now the search is working, but the problem is, the `subMenu` list all the items. Only the first array is getting hided. I need `subMenu` items to be hided. (eg: If I search `one comp` only `one comp` should be displayed. Other items should be hided. Now every items are listing.)

Comment: I have edited the question. Please have a look. Please see the last section.

Answer (score 2):

Okay here's the solution

Change your filterComponents method as this

```
const filterComponents = (e) => {
  let value = e.target.value;
  let components = [ ...this.state.components];
  const filterData = []
  components.map(item => {
    item.subMenu.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      if (cur.secTitle === value) {
        acc.push(cur)
      }
    }, filterData)
  })
  this.setState({ filterResult: filterData });

  };
```

filterData will have filtered result

Hope it helps

Comment: not working. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Comment: @JithinVarghese its working here's sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-breeze-wmcn1 for the filter function. you can see the output on console

Comment: Yes. I can see. I will check this.

Comment: @JithinVarghese if it solved your problem, please accept and up vote the answer, cheers

Comment: @JithinVarghese did you try it i think its wokring

Comment: @JithinVarghese can you make a sandbox snippet, so i can see what's the issue

Answer (score 2):

To solve your problem you have first find the top-level item with the item that you want:

From Glen K answer:

```
let aux = listComponent.filter((component) => {
  return component.subMenu.findIndex((sub) => {
    return sub.secTitle === value;
  }) >= 0;
});
```

Then you filter the subMenu on the filtered list.

```
aux = aux.map(item => {
  item.subMenu = item.subMenu.filter((component) => {
    return component.secTitle === value;
  })
  return item;
})
```

Then save it to your state

```
filterResult = [...aux];

this.setState({ filterResult });
```

Comment: Not working. Showing `TypeError: item.filter is not a function`

Comment: Fixed! try now!

Answer (score 2):

You are only filtering the Components, so **run the filter again on the subMenus** to filter the submenus:

```
let value = event.target.value;
let components = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.components));

// This filter only targets the components themselves...
let filterResult = components.filter(
  component =>
    component.subMenu.findIndex(sub =>
      sub.secTitle.toLowerCase().includes(value)
    ) !== -1
);

// ...so, run the filter again, but this time filter the subMenus
for (let i = 0; i < filterResult.length; i++) {
  filterResult[i].subMenu = [ ...filterResult[i].subMenu];
  filterResult[i].subMenu = filterResult[i].subMenu.filter(
      sub =>
        sub.secTitle.toLowerCase().includes(value)           
  );
}

console.log(filterResult);
```

Other answers provide cleaner solutions, but I feel like you're misunderstanding how the `filter` function works. So, I simply reuse your filter code on the subMenus -- hopefully this illustrates the concept that you are missing.

The Snippet below WORKS! So, please take a look... (I had to make a few assumptions about the rest of your code).

```js
'use strict';

function require(url){ return url; };

const listComponent = [
  {
  id: 0,
  title: "Common",
  subMenu: [
    {
      image: "",
      secTitle: "",
      subTitle: ""
    }
  ]
  },
  {
  id: 1,
  title: "Compute",
  subMenu: [
    {
      image: require("../../assets/images/scaling.png"),
      secTitle: "one comp",
      subTitle: ""
    },
    {
      image: require("../../assets/images/ec2.png"),
      secTitle: "two comp",
      subTitle: ""
    },
    {
      image: require("../../assets/images/lambda.png"),
      secTitle: "three comp",
      subTitle: ""
    },
    {
      image: require("../../assets/images/zone.png"),
      secTitle: "four comp",
      subTitle: ""
    }
    ]
    },
  {
  id: 2,
  title: "Second",
  subMenu: [
    {
      image: "",
      secTitle: "",
      subTitle: ""
    }
  ]
  },
  {
  id: 3,
  title: "Third",
  subMenu: [
    {
      image: "",
      secTitle: "",
      subTitle: ""
    }
  ]
  },
  {
  id: 4,
  title: "Fourth",
  subMenu: [
    {
      image: "",
      secTitle: "",
      subTitle: ""
    }
    ]
   }
];

function KeyboardArrowUp(props) {
  return <span>up</span>;
}


class AppComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      components: listComponent,
      filterResult: listComponent
    };

    this.filterComponents = this.filterComponents.bind(this);
  }
  
  filterComponents = event => {
    let value = event.target.value;
    let components = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.components));

    // This filter only targets the components themselves...
    let filterResult = components.filter(
      component =>
        component.subMenu.findIndex(sub =>
          sub.secTitle.toLowerCase().includes(value)
        ) !== -1
    );

    // ...so, run the filter again, but this time filter the subMenus
    for (let i = 0; i < filterResult.length; i++) {
      filterResult[i].subMenu = [ ...filterResult[i].subMenu];
      filterResult[i].subMenu = filterResult[i].subMenu.filter(
          sub =>
            sub.secTitle.toLowerCase().includes(value)           
      );
    }
      
    console.log(filterResult);

    this.setState({ filterResult });
  };
  
  UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
      components: nextProps.components
    });
  }
  
  openCloseComponent(id) {
    console.log(id);
  }
  
  render() {
    return <div><input type="text" onChange={this.filterComponents} /><br/><ul className="listAll">
            {this.state.filterResult.map((items, key) => (
              <li key={key}>
                <div
                  className="compTitle"
                  onClick={() => this.openCloseComponent(items.id)}
                >
                  <p>{items.title}</p>
                  {this.state.isComOpen === items.id && this.state.isOpen ? (
                    <KeyboardArrowDown className="compArrow" />
                  ) : (
                    <KeyboardArrowUp className="compArrow" />
                  )}
                </div>
                <ul
                  className={
                    this.state.isComOpen === items.id && this.state.isOpen
                      ? "displayBlock secondDrop"
                      : "displayNone"
                  }
                >
                  {items.subMenu.map((submenu, i) => (
                    <li
                      key={i}
                    >
                      <img src={submenu.image} alt="" />
                      <div>
                        <p className="secTitle">{submenu.secTitle}</p>
                        <p className="subTitle">{submenu.subTitle}</p>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  ))}
                </ul>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul></div>
          {this.state.filterResult.length === 0 && (
            <p className="noComp">No components found</p>
          )};
  }
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#app');
ReactDOM.render(<AppComponent />, domContainer);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

First use `filter` to filter the `components`:

```
    let filterResult = components.filter(c => c.subMenu.filter(hasRequiredSecTitle).length > 0);
```

And then filter the `subMenu` collection of filtered components:

```
    filterResult = filterResult.map(c => ({...c, subMenu: c.subMenu.filter(hasRequiredSecTitle)}))
```

So complete function will be:

```
filterComponents = event => {
    let value = event.target.value;
    let components = this.state.components;

    const hasRequiredSecTitle = (subMenu) => subMenu.secTitle === value;
    let filterResult = components.filter(c => c.subMenu.filter(hasRequiredSecTitle).length > 0);
    filterResult = filterResult.map(c => ({...c, subMenu: c.subMenu.filter(hasRequiredSecTitle)}))

    console.log(filterResult);

    this.setState({ filterResult });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some good answers here! Figured I would chime in with mine..

This allows for *case insensitive* searches, and is fairly straight forward..

```js
const { Component } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    filtered: [],
    listComponents: this.props.listComponent || [],
    searchText: this.props.searchText || ""
  };

  componentDidMount = () => 
    this.props.searchText && 
    this.filterComponents();

  handleChange = event =>
    this.setState({ 
      searchText: event.target.value 
    }, () => {
      this.state.searchText 
        ? this.filterComponents() 
        : this.setState({ filtered: [] })
    });

  filterComponents = () => {
    const { searchText, listComponents } = this.state;

    const searchExp = new RegExp(searchText, "i");
    const listCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(listComponents));

    const result = listCopy.filter(item => {
      item.subMenu = item.subMenu.filter(sub => searchExp.test(sub.secTitle));
      return item.subMenu.length && item;
    });
    
    this.setState({ filtered: result })
  };

  render() {
    const { filtered, listComponents, searchText } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={searchText} type="text" />
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(filtered, null, 2)}</pre>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const listComponent = [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: "Common",
    subMenu: [
      {
        image: "",
        secTitle: "",
        subTitle: ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Compute",
    subMenu: [
      {
        image: 'require("../../assets/images/scaling.png")',
        secTitle: "one comp",
        subTitle: ""
      },
      {
        image: 'require("../../assets/images/ec2.png")',
        secTitle: "two comp",
        subTitle: ""
      },
      {
        image: 'require("../../assets/images/lambda.png")',
        secTitle: "three comp",
        subTitle: ""
      },
      {
        image: 'require("../../assets/images/zone.png")',
        secTitle: "four comp",
        subTitle: ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Second",
    subMenu: [
      {
        image: "",
        secTitle: "",
        subTitle: ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Third",
    subMenu: [
      {
        image: "",
        secTitle: "",
        subTitle: ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "Fourth",
    subMenu: [
      {
        image: "",
        secTitle: "",
        subTitle: ""
      }
    ]
  }
];

let index = <App listComponent={listComponent} searchText="oNe" />

render(index, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```